# Abstract algebra isomorphism map help

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $D=\{m+n\sqrt{2} \mid (m,n)\in\Bbb{Z}^2\}$, which is an integral domain. Let $Q$ be its field of fractions and $\phi:D\to Q$ be the usual map. Find an isomorphism: $\alpha:\{a+b\sqrt{2} \mid (a,b)\in\Bbb{Q}^2\}\to Q$ whose restriction to $D$ is $\phi$. You should write the map explicitly, prove that it's injective and surjective.
what is field of fractions. Have no idea about this question. someone help

Comment: Exact (verbatim) duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field containing $D$, you can identify $\text{Frac}(D)$ naturally with

$$\left\{\frac{a+b\sqrt{2}}{c+d\sqrt{2}}:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$

Now, why is this set precisely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?